# WSDL vs REST Pros and Cons

Tags: web-services, rest, wsdl

**Related:**

> [Why would one use REST instead of Web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90451/why-would-one-use-rest-instead-of-web-services)

When deciding whether to implement a web service using SOAP or REST (by which I mean HTTP/XML in a RESTful manner) what should I be aware of and what should I be thinking of? I presume that this isn't a one size fits all thing so how do I choose which to use.

Comment: This question may have some helpful answers as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90451/why-would-one-use-rest-instead-of-web-services

Comment: It depends on the context, both SOAP and REST have their place. You don't typically see Hi-SOAP and lo-SOAP like you hear about REST. The reason being there is specification, and either you follow it or you don't. SOAP finds it use in data centers where you need interoperability between different servers that cannot directly communicate and performance is an important factor. In those cases, it is nice to do SOAP over TCP. SOAP was designed as a transport independence, so essentially you should be able to use it over TCP, MSMQ, etc., REST only deals with HTTP.

Comment: CodeToGlory is right.  As a matter of fact, Microsoft's WCF was designed specifically to make SOAP over any transport medium to be as easy as a value in a config file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SOAP vs REST (differences)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884295/soap-vs-rest-differences)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The following links provide useful information about WSDL vs REST including Pros and Cons

A couple of key points are that

1) SOAP was designed for a distributed computing environment where as REST was designed for a point to point environment.

2) WADL can be used to define the interface for REST services.

http://www.ajaxonomy.com/2008/xml/web-services-part-1-soap-vs-rest
http://ajaxonomy.com/2008/xml/web-services-part-2-wsdl-and-wadl

Comment: REST was designed for distributed systems: "[...] the Representational State Transfer (REST) architectural style for distributed hypermedia systems [...]" (Fielding, 2000) https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm

Answer (score 116):

The two protocols have very different uses in the real world.

SOAP(using WSDL) is a heavy-weight XML standard that is centered around document passing.  The advantage with this is that your requests and responses can be very well structured, and can even use a DTD.  The downside is it is XML, and is very verbose.  However, this is good if two parties need to have a strict contract(say for inter-bank communication).  SOAP also lets you layer things like WS-Security on your documents. SOAP is generally transport-agnostic, meaning you don't necessarily need to use HTTP.

REST is very lightweight, and relies upon the HTTP standard to do it's work.  It is great to get a useful web service up and running quickly.  If you don't need a strict 
API definition, this is the way to go.  Most web services fall into this category.  You can version your API so that updates to the API do not break it for people using old versions(as long as they specify a version).  REST essentially requires HTTP, and is format-agnostic(meaning you can use XML, JSON, HTML, whatever).

Generally I use REST, because I don't need fancy WS-* features.  SOAP is good though if you want computers to understand your webservice using a WSDL.  REST specifications are generally human-readable only.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Why are there envelopes if there's no document? I don't think I said a DTD is a unique characteristic of SOAP. I'm not really in the mood to debate today, sorry. Maybe re-read comments to your answer to this question from almost 3 years ago. I don't think heavy-weight is necessarily a bad thing, sometimes you want Holyfield, but other times Pacquiao gets the job done.  Don't take it the wrong way, and nothing personal :)

Comment: SOAP works with either document-style or RPC-style interfaces. Also, SOAP doesn't use DTD at all, to the best of my knowledge. And you never quantified "heavyweight". Sorry I only just saw your answer, or I'd have downvoted three years ago.

Comment: REST, like SOAP, is protocol independent. It does not rely on HTTP although it is most commonly used that way. I think an important fact that often goes unmentioned is that SOAP vs REST is comparing a w3c standard protocol to a loosely defined pragmatic architectural pattern.

Comment: @jm2 I have never seen rest used outside of HTTP. I would be interested to see how the verbs GET/POST/PUT/DELETE/etc. work in a rest "protocol" without HTTP. Link?

Comment: REST is not related to the HTTP verbs in any way. It is just that if you are building a web service with HTTP, you are automatically covering a lot of the constraints defined by REST.
CoAP (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7252) is a binary protocol similar to HTTP which can also be used to implement the REST-style.

Answer (score 19):

Regarding WSDL (meaning "SOAP") as being "heavy-weight". Heavy matters how? If the toolset is doing all the "heavy lifting" for you, then why does it matter?

I have never yet needed to consume a complicated REST API. When I do, I expect I'll wish for a WSDL, which my tools will gladly convert into a set of proxy classes, so I can just call what appear to be methods. Instead, I suspect that in order to consume a non-trivial REST-based API, it will be necessary to write by hand a substantial amount of "light-weight" code.

Even when that's all done, you still will have translated human-readable documentation into code, with all the attendant risk that the humans read it wrong. Since WSDL is a machine-readable description of the service, it's much harder to "read it wrong".

---

Just a note: since this post, I *have* had the opportunity to work with a moderately complicated REST service. I did, indeed, wish for a WSDL or the equivalent, and I did, indeed, have to write a lot of code by hand. In fact, a substantial part of the development time was spent removing the code duplication of all the code that called different service operations "by hand".

Comment: I think that "light-weight" is about performance, let's say for example to load suggested search terms as you type.  I'm a .NET guy and I really appreciate some IDE features similar to what you say (the automatically generated proxy classes) but for a REST ws. Such thing existe?

Comment: The example you suggest is a simple REST service, and probably hard to "read wrong". Also, anyone who feels that SOAP performs worse needs to back that up with numbers. I haven't had the impression that's what the REST fans were talking about when they say "heavy-weight".

Comment: Heavy-weight is not derogatory, I just meant SOAP gives you a lot, and comes at a bit of a performance and complexity price.  In boxing, a heavyweight can likely do more damage than a lightweight, but a lightweight can get the job done at times when a heavyweight is not required.  Also, the extra "stuff" like WS-Security, or Transactions introduces extra complexity that REST simply does not have.

Comment: "back that up with numbers" - classic flamebait.  I'm a fan of both, but neither is a one-size-fits-all.

Comment: @kekoav: I was responding to Romias saying he thought "light-weight" was about performance. I felt that should be backed up by anyone who feels that way. Also, again, I would not assume better performance without measuring it, and I would not measure, for instance, transactions vs. no transactions, or WS-Security versus HTTPS. It's not flame bait to suggest a statment be verified.

Answer (score 15):

This probably really belongs as comments in several of the above posts, but I don't yet have the rep to do that, so here goes.

I think it is interesting that a lot of the pros and cons often cited for SOAP and REST have (IMO) very little to do with the actual values or limits of the two technologies.  Probably the most cited pro for REST is that it is "light-weight" or tends to be more "human readable".  At one level this is certainly true, REST does have a lower barrier to entry - there is less required structure than SOAP (though I agree with those who have said that good tooling is largely the answer here - too bad much of the SOAP tooling is pretty dreadful).

Beyond that initial entry cost however, I think the REST impression comes from a combination of the form of the request URLs and the complexity of the data exchanged by most REST services.  REST tends to encourage simpler, more human readable request URLs and the data tends to be more digestable as well.  To what extent however are these inherent to REST and to what extent are they merely accidental.  The simpler URL structure is a direct result of the architecture - but it could be equally well applied to SOAP based services.  The more digestable data is more likely to be a result of the lack of any defined structure.  This means you'd better keep your data formats simple or you are going to be in for a lot of work.  So here SOAP's additional structure, which should be a benefit is actually enabling sloppy design and that sloppy design then gets used as a dig against the technology.

So for use in the exchange of structured data between computer systems I'm not sure that REST is inherently better than SOAP (or visa-versa), they are just different.  I think the comparison above of REST vs SOAP to dynamic vs. static typing is a good one.  Where dyanmic languages tend to run in to trouble is in long term maintenance and upkeep of a system (and by long term I'm not talking a year or 2, I'm talking 5 or 10).  It will be interesting to see if REST runs into the same challenges over time.  I tend to think it will so if I were building a distributed, information processing system I would gravitate to SOAP as the communication mechanism (also because of the tranmission and application protocol layering and flexibility that it affords as has been mentioned above).

In other places though REST seems more appropriate.  AJAX between the client and its server (regardless of payload) is one major example.  I don't have much care for the longevity of this type of connection and ease of use and flexibility are at a premimum.  Similarly if I needed quick access to some external service and I didn't think I was going to care about the maintainability of the interaction over time (again I'm assuming this is where REST is going to end up costing me more, one way or another), then I might choose REST just so I could get in and out quickly.

Anyway, they are both viable technologies and depending on what tradeoffs you want to make for a given application they can serve you well (or poorly).

Answer (score 6):

REST is not a protocol; It's an architectural style. Or a paradigm if you want. That means that it's a lot looser defined that SOAP is. For basic CRUD, you can lean on standard protocols such as Atompub, but for most services you'll have more commands than just that.

As a consumer, SOAP can be a blessing or a curse, depending on the language support. Since SOAP is very much modelled on a strictly typed system, it works best with statically typed languages. For a dynamic language it can easily become crufty and superfluous. In addition, the client-library support isn't that good outside the world of Java and .NET

Comment: Is there any valid reason for poor tool support outside of Java and .NET? Is there something missing from the WSDL file that would prevent, say, a Ruby proxy from being created?

Comment: Technically no, but some one has to implement it, and Neither Sun (sorry, Oracle) or Microsoft are going to pay anybody to implement client libraries in Ruby. The SOAP protocol is quite complex. Add to that the fact that all the complexity is in the type system, which is just garbage from a dynamic language perspective. So you can say that SOAP forces the static type systems upon dynamic languages. REST is sort of the opposite way around.

Answer (score 4):

To me we should be careful when we use the word web service. We should all the time specify if we are speaking of SOAP web service, REST web service or other kind of web services because we are speaking about different things here and people don't understand anymore if we named all of them web services.

Basically SOAP web services are very well established for years and they follow a strict specification that describe how to communicate with them based on the SOAP specification.
Now REST web services are a bit newer and basically looks like simpler because they are not using any communication protocol. Basically what you send and receive when you use a REST web service is plain XML. People like it because they can parse the xml the way they want without having to deal with a more sophisticated communication protocol like SOAP.

To me REST services are almost like if you would create a servlet instead of a SOAP web service. The servlet get data in and return data out. The format of the data are xml based. We can also imagine to use something else than xml if we want. For instance tags could be used instead of xml and that would be not REST anymore but something else (Could be even lighter in term of weight because xml is not light by nature). Would we call that still a web service? Yes we could but that will not follow any current standard and this is the main issue here if we start to call everything web services but we can do it the way we want then we are loosing on the interoperability side of the things. That means that the format of the data that is exchanged with the web service is not standardized anymore. That requires then that server and client agree on the format of the data whereas with SOAP this is all predefined already and server and client can interoperate without to know each other because they follow the same standard.

What people don't like with SOAP is that they have hard time to understand it and they cannot generate the queries manually. Computers can do that very well however so this is where we need to be clear: are web services queries and response supposed to be used directly by the end users or do we agree that web services are underneath API called by computer systems based on some normalized standards?

Comment: That would not be REST anymore?

Answer (score 3):

**SOAP**: It can be transported via SMTP also, means we can invoke the service using Email simple text format also

It needs additional framework/engine should be in web service consumer machine to convert SOAP message to respective objects structure in various languages.

**REST**: Now WSDL2.0 supports to describe REST web service also

We can use when you want to make your service as lightweight, example calling from mobile devices like cell phone, pda etc...

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up, @Jenith. No one seems to want to bring this up. WSDL has to do with description. REST is a paradigm. For others: please see the Introduction in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restwsdl/. The original question, thereby (considering its date of entry), shows that the question title is poorly chosen (likely has WSDL 1.0 in mind).

Answer (score 3):

for enterprise systems in which your system is confined within your corporations, its easier and proper to use soap because you are almost in control of clients. it's easier since there a variety of tools which creates classes (proxies) and looks like you are doing your regular OOP which matches your java or .net  environment (in which most corporates use).

I would use REST for internet facing applications for exposing interfaces (like twitter api) since clients can be using javascripts or html or others in which typing is not strict. REST being more liberal makes more sense.

Also for internet facing clients (world wide web), its easier to parse json or xml coming out of a rest interface rather than a purely xml coming from a soap interface. it's hard to use proxies on javascript and javascript does not naturally support objects. If you are using REST with javascript, you would just usually parse the json string and you're off. internet facing interfaces are usually very simple (so most of the time its simple parsing) and does not usually demand consistency that is why REST is adequate enough.

For enterprise applications I don't think REST is adequate because transactions, security, strict typing, schemas play a very important in enterprise applications development that is why SOAP is more suited for them.

My conclusion is that SOAP is for Enterprise systems, REST is for the Internet or WWW. 
You can use it interchangeably but you may find yourself having a difficult time eventually not using the correct tool for the job.

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2):

In defence of REST it closely follows the principles of HTTP and addressability e.g. read operations use GET, update operations use POST etc. I find this to be a far cleaner approach. The Oreilly book RESTful Web Services explains this far better than I can, if you read it I think you would prefer the REST approach

Answer (score 1):

The toolset on the client side would be one. And the familiarity with SOAP services the other. More and more services are going the RESTful route these days, and testing such services can be done with simple cURL examples. 
Although, it's not all that difficult to implement both methods and allow for the widest utilization from clients.

If you need to pick one, I'd suggest REST, it's easier.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers contain a lot of information, but I think there is a philosophical difference that hasn't been pointed out. SOAP was the answer to "how to we create a modern, object-oriented, platform and protocol independent successor to RPC?". REST developed from the question, "how to we take the insights that made HTTP so successful for the web, and use them for distributed computing?"

SOAP is a about giving you tools to make distributed programming look like ... programming. REST tries to impose a style to simplify distributed interfaces, so that distributed resources can refer to each other like distributed html pages can refer to each other. One way it does that is attempt to (mostly) restrict operations to "CRUD" on resources (create, read, update, delete).

REST is still young -- although it is oriented towards "human readable" services, it doesn't rule out introspection services, etc. or automatic creation of proxies. However, these have not been standardized (as I write). SOAP gives you these things, but (IMHO) gives you "only" these things, whereas the style imposed by REST is already encouraging the spread of web services because of its simplicity. I would myself encourage newbie service providers to choose REST unless there are specific SOAP-provided features they need to use.

In my opinion, then, if you are implementing a "greenfield" API, and don't know that much about possible clients, I would choose REST as the style it encourages tends to help make interfaces comprehensible, and easy to develop to. If you know a lot about client and server, and there are specific SOAP tools that will make life easy for both, then I wouldn't be religious about REST, though.

Comment: -1: this doesn't actually answer the question. It says little or nothing about "why should I choose one over the other"?

Comment: I was concentrating on providing information that others didn't -- but have added a conclusion given your prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily transition your WSDL-spewing WCF web components to other uses just by changing your configuration settings.  You can go across HTTP and then also named pipes, tcp, custom protocols, etc without having to change your code.  I believe WCF components may also be easier to set up for stuff like security, two-way calling, transactions, concurrency, etc.

REST pretty much limits you to HTTP (which is fine in many cases).

Answer (score 0):

I know that this discussion is an old one, but after reading all the answers and commented, I believe that everyone missed the most important point about the difference between the 2 systems: SOAP uses complex types to not only give you the data, but validate it and keep it in the strict type designation it was defined for. A WSDL tells you what the data format is, what the data type is, allows you to add reg-ex pattern-style rules, and defines how many times a piece of data must be, and may be, allowed in a request/response.
Rest on the other-hand has none of these mechanisms.

SOAP is complex and heavy because it allows you to send complex heavy hierarchical data. REST is plain text, with the origin and endpoint sorting out the rules.

SOAP is business independent, because it has all the data rules embedded in the document.

The difference between SOAP and REST is that SOAP is a self-contained business oriented schema. REST is a text document.