# Is it possible to use WSDL with a REST webservice?

Tags: web-services, rest, wsdl, wadl

I am new to the area of web-services. Is it possible to use WSDL with REST bindings? Or should I use WADL?

Comment: REST doesn't generally use WSDL.  WSDL is for SOAP.  What -- exactly -- have you read?  Why are you asking this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to use a WSDL with REST bindings, but it's really not necessary.  The simplistic nature of REST make writing code to use that service very easy.  Using a WSDL just adds extra complexity that is just not necessary.

If you're still interested, you can find more information here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restwsdl/

Also, this question may help you:
[WSDL vs REST Pros and Cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840653/wsdl-vs-rest-pros-and-cons)

Comment: @jmort: in what way can one use WSDL with REST bindings? It doesn't seem to make sense, and I'm considering a downvote, but thought you might know something I don't.

Comment: @john: read the IBM article, it details how to employ WSDL 2.0 specs against REST bindings.

Comment: @jro: WSDL 2.0, perhaps, but which consumer of a REST service will know to use a WSDL?

Comment: @john: Agreed -- REST makes WSDL kind of pointless. Nonetheless, it's still feasible.

Comment: @jro: that's not what I said. I said that a consumer of a REST service will likely not understand WSDL at all.

Comment: @john: seriously, it's in the IBM article. Likelihood, believability, take whatever angle you like. I was just pointing out what jmort provided.

Comment: @jro: based on the question and "I'm new to the area of web services", I felt that the OP is not asking for what might work, under some circumstances, but rather what works in general. In general, REST does not use WSDL.

Comment: Well, generating a whole client library for the REST service would be great and feasible if a WDSL (or WADL?) is available. That's a good point for publishing service description.